# Apply batch script to selected video file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I use the following ffmpeg batch file to trim videos

**Trim Video Files.bat**

```
set /p startposition=Enter the start position:
set /p endposition=Enter the end position:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss %startposition% -t %endposition% cut.mp4
pause
```

This works only if the input file is named 'in.mp4', however I would like to be able to just select a video file and drag and drop it on the batch script. In other words how can I make this batch file apply to the selected file only?

Comment: `-t` is not endposition but duration, Change to `-to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I make this batch file apply to the selected file only?

To do this make use of [command lines parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

`%1` refers to the first parameter passed to be the batch file and will represent the name of the file dropped.

Modified batch file:

```
set /p startposition=Enter the start position:
set /p endposition=Enter the end position:
ffmpeg -i %1 -ss %startposition% -t %endposition% cut.mp4
pause
```

- `in.mp4` has been replaced by `%1`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.